# Linux Driver for >2TB drives that are already formatted by Windows DiscWizard?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 3TB Seagate internal drive that I've been using on Windows for a while. My PC doesn't have UEFI, and I needed to boot Windows from the Seagate drive, so I couldn't format it as GPT (Windows doesn't allow booting from a GPT disk with a legacy BIOS). The only way to see all 3TB was to use Seagate's DiscWizard utility. Please note that although DiscWizard also has backup functions, my only use for it was the driver it installs that makes a 3TB drive look like two separate drives, one of 2TB and one of about 800GB. This question has nothing to do with backup.

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 today, on a different drive. I'm not using any kind of dual boot scheme, I just pick which drive to boot from with the BIOS.

When I'm in Ubuntu, I can see the 2TB portion of the Seagate drive, but not the 800GB part. I went to the Seagate website to see if they had a Linux version of DiscWizard, but apparently they don't. The drive is almost full, so I really, really don't want to reformat it.

So my question is, is there any driver for Ubuntu that will allow me to see the last 800GB of my data, without forcing me to back up all 3TB and reformat it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you see both partitions in GParted?  If so, do they both appear as NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to bite the bullet: Back up the disk, repartition it, and restore the data. I admit that I know nothing about this DiscWizard software, but I know from experience that such things tend to be non-standard and to be unusable outside of their designed environments (in this case, Windows).

Moving forward, see my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390119/3tb-hdd-and-legacy-bios) (which it seems you've also answered). You can get access to the disk in other ways via tools like DUET or Clover, or by using an (ugly and dangerous, but at least somewhat well-understood) hybrid MBR.