# 3TB HDD in legacy BIOS or EFI?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt, mbr

How do I mark the [unallocated](https://askubuntu.com/q/1232237/45156) space as bootable?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l | grep Disk
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.93 GiB, 2049204224 bytes, 4002352 sectors
Disk /dev/loop1: 27.9 MiB, 28405760 bytes, 55480 sectors
Disk /dev/loop2: 54.97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Disk /dev/loop3: 240.82 MiB, 252493824 bytes, 493152 sectors
Disk /dev/loop4: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Disk /dev/loop5: 49.8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Disk /dev/sda: 2.75 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: ST3000DM001-9YN1
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5771c34f
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.3G     0  8.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G  1.6M  1.7G   1% /run
/dev/sr0        2.8G  2.8G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      2.1G  2.1G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            8.4G  702M  7.7G   9% /
tmpfs           8.4G  126M  8.3G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  8.2k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           8.4G  541k  8.4G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.7G   95k  1.7G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop2       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop3      253M  253M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop4       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop5       53M   53M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

gparted shows:

[image: gparted]

where I'm not seeing an option to change the flag...

This [has](https://askubuntu.com/q/390119/45156) to be change to `EFI` to dual-boot?  Unfortunately, due to licensing, it's not an option to run Windows as VM with just an OEM license (for all [practical](https://askubuntu.com/q/1231108/45156) purposes).

Answer (score 2):

You definetely need a GPT partition table on drives larger than 2.2TB. With the old `msdos` partition table you are limited to 2.2 TB and can't make use of the full amount of space.

Reference: https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Drive_Partition_Limits_Fact_Sheet.pdf

If you install Windows on a GPT drive, it must be UEFI. Linux generally can be installed in either UEFI-mode or legacy-mode (the latter needs a bios_boot partition).

One more point: You can't mark unallocated space as bootable, unallocated space is **not a partition**.